# Change Binding According to Value in UserInterface

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I am implementing an interface for sensors. Therefore i created a class **TestSensor**, a ViewModel **MainViewModel** and the GUI itself.

In the GUI i have ComboBox that has several units that it can display. The standard-unit is microstrain and this is also the unit the data gets read in.
After the data is read in, i managed to convert it to the other units needed. Those values are saved in the Sensor objects themselves.

**My Problem now**:

How can i do it, that the Labels display the chosen unit? So that when i change the unit from *microStrain* to e.g. *ton*, it will update all the Labels to the values stored in *ton*?

I know about converters, but there must be some other way especially cause i have more than one possible conversion! Im relatively new to XAML and C# and so i really hope someone can point out a solution that makes this possible.

Here's the Code:

Class TestSensor

```
 class TestSensor : ModelBase
{
    double sensorDatauStrain;
    public double SensorDatauStrain
    {
        get { return sensorDatauStrain; }
        set
        {
            if (sensorDatauStrain != value)
            {
                sensorDatauStrain = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    double sensorDatakNewton;
    public double SensorDatakNewton
    {
        get { return sensorDatakNewton; }
        set
        {
            if (sensorDatakNewton != value)
            {
                sensorDatakNewton = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    double sensorDataTon;
    public double SensorDataTon
    {
        get { return sensorDataTon; }
        set
        {
            if (sensorDataTon != value)
            {
                sensorDataTon = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    double sensorDatausTon;
    public double SensorDatausTon
    {
        get { return sensorDatausTon; }
        set
        {
            if (sensorDatausTon != value)
            {
                sensorDatausTon = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    string sensorName;
    public string SensorName
    {
        get { return sensorName; }
        set
        {
            if (sensorName != value)
            {
                sensorName = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public TestSensor(string name, double ustrain)
    {
        this.SensorName = name;
        this.SensorDatauStrain = ustrain;
    }

    public void UpdateUnits(double emodule, double diameter)
    {
        SensorDatakNewton = (SensorDatauStrain * 1000000) / (emodule * diameter);
        SensorDataTon = 9.81 * SensorDatakNewton;
        SensorDatausTon = 1.1 * SensorDatausTon; 
    }
}
```

The sensors represented in the VM:

```
public MainViewViewModel()
    {
        Sensor11 = new TestSensor("Sensor 1.1", 0);
        Sensor12 = new TestSensor("Sensor 1.2", 0);
        Sensor21 = new TestSensor("Sensor 2.1", 0);
        Sensor22 = new TestSensor("Sensor 2.2", 0);
        Sensor31 = new TestSensor("Sensor 3.1", 0);
        Sensor32 = new TestSensor("Sensor 3.2", 0);
        Sensor41 = new TestSensor("Sensor 4.1", 0);
        Sensor42 = new TestSensor("Sensor 4.2", 0);
        SideFactors = new Factors(100, 210);
        LimitPos = 0;
        LimitNeg = 0;
    }

    //-----------------Chosen unit------------------
    Unit unit;
    public Unit Unit
    {
        get { return unit; }
        set
        {
            if (unit != value)
            {
                unit = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

    }



    //----------------One of the Sensors------------------------------
    TestSensor sensor11;
    public TestSensor Sensor11
    {
        get { return sensor11; }
        set
        {
            if (sensor11 != value)
            {
                sensor11 = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
                this.OnPropertyChanged("SubTotal1");
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Average");
            }
        }
    }
```

And heres the XAML-Code:

The Label:

```
<Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,1,1" FontSize="8" Content="{Binding Sensor11.SensorDatauStrain, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

The ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" IsReadOnly="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                     ItemsSource="{Binding Source={data:EnumBindingSource {x:Type data:Unit}}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Unit, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

This is how the GUI looks like:

[on the top left corner you see sensor 1.1, then sensor 1.2 etc. this is the place where the value of the Sensor 1.1 should be visible IN the chosen unit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0oOW.png)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. For the Label bind the Content to the ComboBox's `SelectedValue` property instead of binding it to `Sensor11`.

For example:

```
<Label Margin="86,48,0,0"
       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
       VerticalAlignment="Top"
       Content="{Binding SelectedValue,
                         ElementName=comboBox}" />
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox"
          Width="120"
          Margin="94,21,0,0"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          SelectedIndex="0">
          <!-- ... --->
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: You mean something like 
`Content={x:Type data:Unit}` ? This just ends up in the Label showing "Namespace.Data.Unit"...
I need the programm to kind of change the Binding expression depending on the chosen unit!

Comment: @Laurence Sorry. I miswrote because I copied the wrong piece of code! I've updated my answer with a proper piece of code instead of confused words. :) Essentially, the label takes the combo's selected value.

Comment: Now i understand what you mean, but there is a general misunderstanding.  I updated the Information...would be great if you could check again.

Comment: I think I understand better now. You don't want to just show what is literally in the combo but rather the value that corresponds to that value type. So in effect, you need to change the binding every time the combo's selection changes. I think what you may need to use is a DataTrigger. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.multidatatrigger%28v=vs.100%29.aspx I'll try and post some working code later today.

Comment: You're very welcome. One more link to help: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-datatrigger-event-trigger/